# Best way to have only one Data Fetch for both methods in a Spring Controller Which is executed at same time

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, architecture

In Spring MVC, i have two methods :

```
public ModelAndView getLegislations(HttpServletRequest  
request,HttpServletResponse response)  { 
List list = getLegistService().fetchLislation();     
// returns model and view object
}

public ModelAndView getLegislationsJSON(HttpServletRequest request,  
HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
List list = getLegistService().fetchLislation()
// returns JSON Object
}
```

Both methods are executed at same time using jQuery Ajax.
One returns a modelandview Object and the other returns JSON.

What will be the best way to have only one Data Fetch for both methods. I need this because the result provide by `getLegistService().fetchLislation()` is the same.
Thanks

Comment: Could you add controller annotation ? Do you make one request or two ? Provide us the request you made please

Comment: I am using Spring 2 and not using annotations, both methods in Multiaction controller. Two different Ajax request is used for both both methods separately.

Comment: You could add a cache so several fetches don't matter.

Comment: Cache in Jquery or in Hibernate

Comment: Can't you work with just one method and based on accepted content-type, convert to json or model and view? This seems like an unnecessary duplication of code, unless you have other reasons. BTW, what is the problem with this approach? You are fetching it upon a request. Even if it's one data fetch, the scenario is the same as the one when there is double the number of requests, right?

Comment: Are the calling function (client side) on the same page and are they making call on same event? what do you mean by "Both methods are executed at same time"

Comment: I mean the two requests getLegislationsJSON and getLegislations are executed at same time

Answer (score 0):

Use a cache behind the service - a query cache. E.g. in EclipseLink you have "query-results-cache". In Hibernate [1] you have to add this to the persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
```

But you could also implement your own cache using guava cache or something else. Then your service sends the fetch to the cache instead of directly asking the DB [2].

[1] https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Clustering_Guide/4/html/ch04s02s03.html
[2] https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained

Answer (score 0):

As per your service methods i dont see any arguments passed, so it is kind of constant data, caching using the web server scope is more than enough.

- if the data is not growing at the back end, then you can put the
  `List` object in the application scope, so try to get the object from
  the application sope if not present hit the DB, get the data put it
  in the application scope and from then onwards return this cached
  data.
- If data is growing, then consider what are the variables, use session
  scope and follow the same statergy as above.

Answer (score 0):

Caching can be one option as Vishnu and Swinkler has mentioned, but if you want to make only one call from client and both the calls are together (as I understand from your question), you can use [publisher subscriber](http://codeasp.net/articles/javascript/256/javascript-design-pattern-publisher-subscriber-pattern) design pattern for making call and make same ModelAndView object available to both the subscriber. once you have object you can convert that to JSON client side as well.

Comment: See I have a Web page on one side its a graph and the other side its a form,The graph needs a JSON format.

Comment: and both are making call to this server on page load?

Comment: How we can implement Observer Pattern in this scenario ?